# Pivot a single row and paste them among each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot

I'm kinda new to using pivot. How can I pivot this record from this:

```
Id    P1AVERAGE    P2AVERAGE    P3AVERAGE   -> column name
1     1.25         1.50         1.75
2     2.00         2.25         2.50
```

to this:

```
AVERAGENAME    AVERAGESCORE
p1Average      1.25
p2Average      1.50
p3Average      1.75
p1Average      2.00
p2Average      2.25
p3Average      2.50
```

I'm using SQL Server 2019.

I tried an approach with this:

```
SELECT *
INTO #TempExport
FROM  tbl

DECLARE @Id INT
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #TempExport)
BEGIN 
    SELECT TOP 1 @Id = Id FROM #TempExport

    --pivot function--

    DELETE #TempExport WHERE Id = @Id
END
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to unpivot data is using CROSS APPLY provided all columns in question are of the same type

```
select pvt.AVERAGENAME,pvt.AVERAGESCORE
from tbl
cross apply (
    values 
      ('p1Average',p1Average),
      ('p2Average',p2Average),
      ('p3Average',p3Average)
    ) pvt (AVERAGENAME,AVERAGESCORE)
```